# How ReSharper chooses whether to show library types in hierarchies inspector?

Tags: c#, types, resharper, hierarchy, inspect

Sometimes ReSharper is kind and shows all types. Sometimes only my own types. Can't follow the logic behind this... 
How to force it to show all types? Tried with Navigate -> Derived Types and Inspect -> Type Hierarchies.

Visual Studio 2013

ReSharper 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure under what circumstances you're getting ReSharper to show types, but the rule of thumb is that the default search scope for Find Usages or Go To Derived Type, etc. is solution scope. So ReSharper will only show usages and derived types that are defined in the current solution. However, if you invoke these methods on a type that's defined in a reference (from the Object Browser, Assembly Explorer, or a decompiled type in the code editor), then the search scope will be solution + references. This means that Find Usages and Go To Derived Type, etc. will include types defined in references, as well as from the current solution.

For Find Usages, you can also invoke the Advanced Find Usages dialog to specify the scope - including project, solution and solution and references.